# How i print a number in caporal js

Tags: javascript

I want to print a number in caporal js. But the result not i want because return true/false. I want to if not exist passing a parameter number,default value is 32.
This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { program } = require("@caporal/core");

program

  .command("random", "Generate random alphanumeric")
  .option("--length", "length of number", program.NUMERIC, 32)
  .action(({ logger, args, options }) => {
    let length = options.length;
    let letters = options.letters
    logger.info(length);
  });

program.run();
```

if i run on terminal

let say

./app.js random

will be result 32

if i run
./app.js random --length=10

will be result 10

i have tried found the problem, but i cant. How i must repair my code so appropriated with i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { program } = require("@caporal/core");

program

  .command("random", "Generate random alphanumeric")
  .option("--length <num>", "length of number", {
    validator: program.NUMBER,
    default: 32,
  })
  .action(({ logger, args, options }) => {
    let length = options.length;
    let letters = options.letters
    logger.info(length);
  });

program.run();
```

options in `.option` there are 3 arguments, including:

1. Option synopsis is a string like '-f, --force', or '-f, --file <file>', or '--with-openssl [path]'
2. Option description in the form of a string
3. Options Additional parameters containing the custom command options

You can change `--length` to `--length <num>` to add the number value after the `--length` command. Then, you remove `program.NUMERIC, 32` and add this code

```
{
     validator: program.NUMBER,
     defaults: 32,
}
```

to define a validator into the number data type and contains the default number is 32.